# Program segfaults when ran with GDB

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, kali-linux, c, debugging

this is my first time posting a question here, so forgive me if I don't give enough details. I will provide any extra details that are requested.

Basically, I'm practicing a buffer overflow, and I'm getting this weird segfault only when the program I'm testing is run with gdb:
[image: gdb issue]

This is what the program looks like normally:
[image: normal]

The program zip file comes with a glibc folder with shared object files in it:[image]

Also, this error occurs even without gef installed on gdb.

As for the things I've tried to fix this issue (all of which have failed):

1. Reinstalling and updating gdb
2. Running gdb as root (without gef too)
3. updating Linux
4. Reinstalling the program zipfile and unzipping it
5. Googling this error online and trying to find a solution.

All I know is that, when run in gdb, it seems like it's having a problem accessing a specific address in ./glibc/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, and at that address, I believe is the endbr64 command. I don't know where to go from there though.

As for some details about the binary itself:[image: filedata]

So, what's the actual problem, and how do I resolve this? If any more information or screenshots are needed, I'm willing to provide them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at the "The program no longer exists" message...

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text.  They are inaccessible to browsers for the blind and can be in violation of disability discrimination legislation.

Comment: @ThoriumBR that message is because the program got terminated after the segmentation fault. That has nothing to do with the error at hand lol.